# GetPartitions got skewed partitions?

Tags: c#, plinq

Running the following code in C# interactive window

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

var l = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);

Partitioner.Create(l).GetPartitions(4)
  .Select(x => { 
    var s = ""; 
    while (x.MoveNext()) { s += x.Current.ToString() + ","; }; 
    return s; 
  })
```

returns

```
Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<IEnumerator<int>, string>
  { "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,", "", "", "" }
```

It seems one partition got all the values? I tried it with large size `Enumerable.Range(0, 12000)` and all the elements still go in the first partition.

---

I want to make sure the following extension method can partition the list evenly.

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
        select Task.Run(async delegate {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current);
        }));
}
```

Comment: There is a comment in the source code: *For example, by default, some form of buffering and chunking will be employed to achieve 
 optimal performance in the common scenario where an IEnumerable<> implementation is fast and non-blocking*. See https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent/PartitionerStatic.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say that it is your code that causes it: you enumerate only one partition, but the partitions are "filled" on request.

You want a simple test?

```
Partitioner.Create(l).GetPartitions(4)
  .Skip(1)
  .Select(x => { 
    var s = ""; 
    while (x.MoveNext()) { s += x.Current.ToString() + ","; }; 
    return s; 
  })
```

Now it is another partition that gets all the values :-) But wasn't the first partition that was getting all the values? Now it is the second one :-)

More correct test would be:

```
var l = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);

var parts = Partitioner.Create(l).GetPartitions(4);

string[] bufs = new string[parts.Count];

while (true)
{
    int countFinished = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (parts[i].MoveNext())
        {
            bufs[i] += parts[i].Current + ",";
        }
        else
        {
            countFinished++;
        }
    }
    if (countFinished == parts.Count)
    {
        break;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bufs[i]);
}
```

I'm enumerating the four partitions at the same time. This will distribute all the numbers equally between partitions.

Comment: I've updated the question. I want to make sure the extension method can partition the list evenly, will it?

Comment: @ca9163d9 don't know. I don't use plinq, so I don't know anything... The response I gave you was based on a feeling

Comment: It's skewed. I've posted another question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727086/plinq-get-skewed-partition-from-partitionar

Comment: @ca9163d9 - I have noticed the same thing and was wondering if you managed to "unskew" that method? I'm using the same kind of extension method as yours